# Проблема с requests proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Недавно нашел хорошую библиотеку для работы с сетью, все устраивало пока не дошел до пункта прокси. Почему то возникает такая проблема

```
http_proxy  = "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
https_proxy = "https://127.0.0.1:8080"

proxyDict = { 
              "http"  : http_proxy, 
              "https" : https_proxy,
            }

r = requests.get('http://site.ru/', proxies=proxyDict)
```

Всё прекрасно работает, но как только я получаю переменную http_proxy с левых источников, например, считываю с файла, ничего не работает,дает ошибку:

> requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.LocationParseError: Failed to parse: 127.0.0.1:8080

Не понимаю, почему она возникает. Пробовал print'ом выводить значение, выводит нужную мне строку. Пробовал устанавливать кодировку, utf8, тоже результата никакого. Скину полный пример кода (неработающего):

```
#!/opt/python3.3/bin/python3
import requests
pr = open('proxy.txt')
proxy = pr.readlines()
http_proxy  = proxy[0]
https_proxy = "https://127.0.0.1:8080"
proxyDict = { 
              "http"  : http_proxy, 
              "https" : https_proxy,
            }

r = requests.get('http://site.ru/', proxies=proxyDict)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http_proxy  = proxy[0].strip()
```